# Add a custom form only to a particular content type

Tags: forms

is there any way to add a form only to a particular content type so that in all nodes of my content type, say, My_Custom_Content, that form is displayed but not on any other nodes

Comment: do you mean while displaying the node or while adding or editing the node?

Comment: while displaying the node

Comment: i think you already got the answer. if it is a simple form to collect some info from the user then a webform would be good enough as well.

Comment: @MohammedShameem...actually i do not want to collect any information as such..on clicking the button, an email would be sent to admin and some changes would be performed in the user table...I tried custom coding with rules but was unable to do so and hence ventured into this area

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, I think you are trying to display your custom form in the node view of a particular content type. You can do this in two ways.

The first approach is to implement [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) from the module level.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
    if($view_mode == 'full'){
        if($node->type == 'your_content_type'){                 
            $node->content['my_form'] = array(     
                '#markup' => drupal_get_form('your_form_id'), 
                '#weight' => 1,
            );
        }
    }   
}
```

The second approach is to implement [hook_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) from the theme level.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($variables['node'])) {
    if($variables['node']->type == 'your_content_type'){
        $variables['content']['my_form'] = drupal_get_form('your_form_id');
    }   
  }
}
```